# LSF parent job waiting for child

Tags: unix, lsf

I am using **LSF bsub** command to submit jobs in Unix environment. However the LSF job is waiting for child jobs to finish.

Here is an example (details about sample scripts below):

1. **Without LSF**: If I submit `parent.ksh` in Unix without using `LSF`, i.e in command prompt I type `./parent.ksh`, `parent.ksh` get's submitted and get's completed in a second without waiting for child jobs `script1.ksh` and `script2.ksh` since these jobs have been submitted in background mode. This is typical behaviour in Unix.
2. **With LSF**: However if I submit my `parent.ksh` using `LSF`, i.e. `bsub parent.ksh`, `parent.ksh` wait for 180 seconds(thats the longest time taken by child number 2 i.e. script2.ksh)  after submission. Please note I have expcluded time taken by job in pending status.

This is something I was not expecting, how can I ensure this does not happen?

I had checked, `script1.ksh` and `script2.ksh` was invoked in both cases.

**parent.ksh:**

```
#!/bin/ksh<br>
/abc/def/script1.ksh &<br>
/abc/def/script1.ksh &<br><br>
```

**script1.ksh:**

```
#!/bin/ksh<br>
sleep 80<br><br>
```

**script2.ksh:**

```
#!/bin/ksh<br>
sleep 180
```

Comment: can you please try **bsub parent.ksh &** and share the result here?

Comment: same result after trying bsub parent.ksh &

Comment: Hmm..I have not used LSF before but I suspect that LSF does some background monitoring of the processes it has created and hence runs until all its children have finished. It well may be expected behaviour but again, I may be wrong.

Comment: The whole point of a batch scheduler is to **prevent** users from doing what you are trying to do.  Its LSF's job to track what is running on the execution host, so that it can accurately manage the machine.

If you double fork and setsid() you can probably fool LSF.  But, LSF v9.1 will come with support for cgroups, which AFAIK will close this loophole.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason is that LSF tracks process tree of your job, thus LSF job only completes till these two background processes exits. So you can try to create a new process group for the background process under a new session.